# Android SDK manager throw Exception with Java 9

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools, java-9

Using `sdk-tools-darwin-4333796 (26.1.1)` with Java 9 when running `sdkmanager` is throwing :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: I think java 9 doesn't contain this file path to the specified file. Take a look at this similar question. It might help you with your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Comment: Yes with `./sdkmanager --add-modules java.xml.bind` it does run without error but meanwhile it doesn't allow me to add any arguments to it (like `./sdkmanager --version --add-modules java.xml.bind` would simply bring up manual.

Comment: @AeroWang `Warning: Unknown argument --add-modules` at my install.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Edit `sdkmanager` file, find `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` and add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` argument to it.

For instance, if your `sdkmanager` file has

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"'
```

change it to

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" --add-modules java.xml.bind'
```

---

*Update*:  the above works for Java 9 and 10.  The `java.xml.bind` module was removed in Java 11, and will not be found.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-11-relnote.html#JDK-8190378

---

***Additional Update***: Apparently there are two versions of the `sdkmanager`, a deprecated one that requires Java8 and a new one that works with Java 11.  See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782803/)

Comment: Thanks for this. While you're there, it's worth making the same change to ./avdmanager too.

Comment: Thank it works for me. I have changed like below :

DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" --add-modules java.xml.bind'

Comment: You can also set instead the JAVA_OPTS environment variable to the same value, without the need to modify the scripts.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works for me. [Arch Linux x64 - OpenJDK 10]

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work anymore. The weird thing is that you can run SDK Manager from the Android Studio GUI and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It throws error "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found"

Comment: me too: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found