# Getting Android sdkmanager to run with Java 11

Tags: android, java-11

I am facing a problem while running Android `sdkmanager` with Java 11 (Not studio, only SDK tools). I don't want to install JDK 8 or something similar. Is there a way to fix this for Android `sdkmanager` with JDK 11?

I have gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-android-sdk-with-java-9/47150411) and it doesn't offer command line fix for java 11. Any other workaround possible?

Comment: are you facing a similar issue as the linked question OR what is it that you're facing an issue with? Have you tried running with Java11 to start off with?

Comment: It may help if you would exactly name the problem and not say "a problem". Edit your question and add the error message and/or the stack trace.

Comment: I've got the same issue. The exception that is thrown is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Answer (score 58):

UPDATE: as explained in another answer, the sdkmanager from the new command line tool supports JDK 11+. The old sdkmanager has not received updates in years, so this workaround should not be necessary. Check @dmertins answer for links and more details.

---

If anyone is looking for a Linux fix on Java 11. I built this on top of previous answers

```
cd Android/tools
mkdir jaxb_lib
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/activation.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.3/jaxb-impl-2.3.3.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar -O jaxb_lib/istack-commons-runtime.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.3.3/jaxb-xjc-2.3.3.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.3.3/jaxb-jxc-2.3.3.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar
```

After the download finishes (make sure all files were downloaded OK), you have to edit sdkmanager and avdmanager scripts in the tools/bin directory.  You can do this manually or automatically.

From Simon Ruggier answer (doesn't work on mac unless you use gnu-sed):

```
sed -ie 's%^CLASSPATH=.*%\0:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/*%' bin/sdkmanager bin/avdmanager
```

Or manually, scroll down to the CLASSPATH variable, and add the new jars we just downloaded like this:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/activation.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar:<etc etc...DO NOT REMOVE THE OTHER JARS!...>
```

Comment: tried it on my friend mac it also works after installing wget

Comment: MacOS user here -- this is the best answer I've found on the Internet as of 12 Sep 2019.

Comment: macOS 10.14.6, Java: 13.0.1 2019-10-15,still error here ```./sdkmanager --version
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector$1 (file:/Users/limao/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) ...```,

Comment: I added a more convenient version of this answer as a separate answer. I'm not out for Internet points, so I was initially going to comment here as a suggestion, but there's a maximum comment length, and no support for code blocks in comments, so I had to put it in a separate answer for it to be useful. If this answer gets updated to incorporate the improvement, let me know and I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I added your suggestions. It´s a nice shortcut.

Comment: On macOS Big Sur, `sed` messed up the classpath declaration. I had to use GNU sed with `brew install gnu-sed`.

Comment: This should not be necessary if using the new "command line tools" package, which is JDK11+ compatible. See fresher answer below

Comment: Thanks Mike, I updated the answer to point to @dmertins's answer, which is way more updated than this old workaround. I also transformed it into a community wiki, so others can update it.

Answer (score 44):

The `sdkmanager` that comes with the deprecated **SDK Tools** package doesn't support JDK 8 and is no longer receiving updates since september 2017. More information [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67495440) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools).

The `sdkmanager` included in the new **Command-Line Tools** package supports JDK 11 and it can be downloaded from the Android Studio download page, in the **Command line tools only** [section](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools). There's no need to download any other files or to hack with the `sdkmanager` script, however you will need to update your PATH setting, e.g. on Linux: `$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` instead of `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`

Although deprecated, the old Tools package is still being installed with Android Studio 4.1.1 by default. This [post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67495440#comment43) explains why.

Comment: This is the correct answer in March 2021. Typically it's a PATH issue now, new command line tools (`$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin`) are not in the PATH before the old tools (`$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`) but either referencing them directly or reorganize your paths, and you've got modern JDK11-compatible sdkmanager.

Comment: This advice seems to be out of date as of November 2021.  There is no `latest` folder in the offical download for the Android SDK command line tools, only the Java-11-incompatible `sdkmanager`.

Comment: Is there a chance to install the v11-compatible tools? The version that they offer is no longer compatible with Java 11.

Answer (score 8):

For those of you seeing this issue in Travis CI:
I was seeing this error while attempting to accept the license agreement for build tools 30.0.2, targeting Android 30, with Java 11 for a travis CI build.
Applying this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65782803/6500352) I ended up with this working yml

```
os: linux
language: android
jdk: openjdk11

android:
 components:
   - tools
   - platform-tools
   - tools
   - extra-android-m2repository
env:
  global:
    - TARGET_VERSION=30
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=30.0.2
    - ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk

before_install:
  - touch $HOME/.android/repositories.cfg
  - wget "https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7302050_latest.zip" -O commandlinetools.zip
  - unzip commandlinetools.zip -d $ANDROID_HOME/
  - yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-${TARGET_VERSION}" --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME
  - yes | $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION}" --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME

before_script:
 - chmod +x gradlew
script:
- ./gradlew your_command_here
```

Comment: tools and platform-tools are not needed under android components since you're manually fetching them. build-tools is also downloaded on demand by Android Gradle plugin so platforms:android-30 is the only component you need.

Comment: This works for Travis CI and Java 11. Yes tools, platform-tools, and build-tools can be removed without causing problems.

Answer (score 4):

Download jxab and jaf, put them all into classpath.

e.g.

sdkmanager.bat

```
...
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;mylib\jaxb-ri\lib\jaxb-api.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;mylib\jaxb-ri\lib\jaxb-core.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;mylib\jaxb-ri\lib\jaxb-impl.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;mylib\jaxb-ri\lib\jaxb-jxc.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;mylib\jaxb-ri\lib\jaxb-xjc.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;mylib\jaf-1.1.1\activation.jar

@rem Execute sdkmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
...
```

Comment: where can i get jaxb, and jaf respectively ?
from blind web search it shows up java ee, and some search result shows that jaf is somewhat bundled or something.

Comment: search https://mvnrepository.com

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar
http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.0.2/jaxb-impl-2.0.2.jar
http://repository.ops4j.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.0.2/jaxb-xjc-2.0.2.jar
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.3.2/jaxb-jxc-2.3.2.jar

Comment: Finally. I made it work with java 18

Comment: This helped me in 2022! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more automated version of Emilio's answer (thanks!):

```sh
cd Android/tools
mkdir jaxb_lib
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/activation.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.3/jaxb-impl-2.3.3.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar -O jaxb_lib/istack-commons-runtime.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.3.3/jaxb-xjc-2.3.3.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.3.3/jaxb-jxc-2.3.3.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar -O jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar
# Append jaxb_lib to the CLASSPATH in sdkmanager and avdmanager
sed -ie 's%^CLASSPATH=.*%\0:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/*%' bin/sdkmanager bin/avdmanager
```

The jar directory also doesn't belong under `bin`, so these instructions place it one level higher.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issues according to previous answers, that you'd better to use more recent `jaxb-impl` jar such as `2.3.1` to avoid the reflection warning.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar

Also if we put all jar files into `${APP_HOME}/lib` and then append `${APP_HOME}/lib/*` to `CLASSPATH`, the java will pick up all jar files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Apple Silicon or don't have wget installed:

```
cd Android/sdk/tools # or Android/tools
mkdir jaxb_lib
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar -o jaxb_lib/activation.jar
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.3/jaxb-impl-2.3.3.jar -o jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar -o jaxb_lib/istack-commons-runtime.jar
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.3.3/jaxb-xjc-2.3.3.jar -o jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/2.3.0.1/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar -o jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/2.3.3/jaxb-jxc-2.3.3.jar -o jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar -o jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar

# Add To CLASSPATH
sed -ie 's%^CLASSPATH=.*%\0:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/*%' bin/sdkmanager bin/avdmanager
# Add this manually on newline after CLASSPATH
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/activation.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar:$APP_HOME/jaxb_lib/istack-commons-runtime.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
>           at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>           at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>           at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>           at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
>           at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           ... 5 more

Using Java 12, these are the steps I followed to bypass this warning. Thanks to Wang Qian.

Navigate to the path where the android sdk is installed such as the following.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

Edit **sdkmanager.bat** with a text editor such as notepad.

Find the following lines at approximately line 70.

```
@rem Execute sdkmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

Just above those lines, paste the following code.

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\mylib\jaxb-api.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\mylib\jaxb-core.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\mylib\jaxb-impl.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\mylib\jaxb-jxc.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\mylib\jaxb-xjc.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%APP_HOME%\mylib\activation.jar
```

Create a new folder called mylib in the tools folder of your android sdk installation.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib
```

Download the latest version of the following 6 jar files and place them in the mylib folder.

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-core
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-xjc
- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-jxc/

Remove the versioning in the filenames to match the filenames set in the sdkmanager.bat file. You should now have the following files.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib\activation.jar
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib\jaxb-api.jar
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib\jaxb-core.jar
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib\jaxb-impl.jar
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib\jaxb-jxc.jar
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\tools\mylib\jaxb-xjc.jar
```

All set! Now run your sdkmanager --update command

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying [Wang Qian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774346/9578295), I got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION`. This might because the versions of jaxb-impl and jaxb-core are not matching. Make sure you download the same version of these two libraries, such as `2.3.0.1`.

After that, I got another exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/FinalArrayList`. I found out this is because we are missing another library: [istack-commons-runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime). Download it and put it into the classpath as well.

---

So the full list of library dependencies that need to add to classpath specifically should be:

- jaxb-api
- jaxb-core
- jaxb-impl
- jaxb-jxc
- jaxb-xjc
- activation
- istack-commons-runtime

---

After this, you should be able to run `sdkmanager` but with a warning of illegal reflective access. You can ignore it without any problems. If you are interested in it, have a quick search. You'll find lots of questions on Stack Overflow regarding this warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on macOS using the [android-sdk](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/android-sdk) formula from Homebrew, it's discontinued and only supports Java 8. Quoting its formula page:

> android-sdk requires Java 8. You can install it with:
> brew install --cask homebrew/cask-versions/temurin8
>
> android-sdk has been officially discontinued upstream. It may stop
> working correctly (or at all) in recent versions of macOS.

For Java 11 and newer, you can install the [android-commandlinetools](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/android-commandlinetools) formula.

```
brew install android-commandlinetools
```

Don't forget to set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable pointing to your "new" Android SDK directory:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools
```