# Flutter - Android license status unknown

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

I've been looking around extensively to try and figure out why I continued getting this exception. I've seen similar issues, but none that could resolve my issue.

whenever I run `flutter doctor` This pops up:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    X Android license status unknown.
    Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
    See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
    https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I have checked and my environment variables are all set

Then when I type `flutter doctor --android-licenses` I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

Can you please help, I am confused and anything would really help

Comment: you installed whole android studio or just the cmd tools?

Comment: all of Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `flutter doctor --android-licenses` simply invokes `<ANDROID_HOME>/tools/bin/sdkmanager` from Android SDK. `sdkmanager` is a small wrapper that finds JVM and starts java program.

The following line implies that Java 9+ is used to run the `sdkmanager`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
```

Unfortunately, `sdkmanager` is not capable to run on new Java versions. So there might be few solutions:

1. Set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to JDK 1.8 before running `flutter doctor`. E.g. `set JAVA_HOME=...` on Windows or `export JAVA_HOME=...` on linux
2. [Add missing libraries and get `sdkmanager` running on Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076422/getting-android-sdkmanager-to-run-with-java-11)

Comment: Thanks, I installed jdk 8 and set my JAVA_HOME variable to it and it ended up working :)