# Using andoird "sdkmanager" with OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, android, sdk, openjdk-11

I want to use Android `sdkmanager` with OpenJDK instead of Oracle JDK and I've installed the package `default-jre` in ubuntu 18.04.But when I run `sdkamanger` I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150410/failed-to-run-sdkmanager-list-with-java-9) and it has been suggested to add the option `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee` to the variable `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` in the file `sdkmanager`.But since I want to use **OpenJDK** I don't have the module `java.se.ee`.

I have almost no experience in Java and I just want to install Android NDK to use with Qt and C++,not java or kotlin.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I faced this same error.
But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55982976/11537839) answer resolved my issue.
Download all the mentioned files in "Android/tools/bin". Then Edit both `sdkmanager and avdmanager scripts` .
Add the following lines and do not remove the other Jars:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/bin/jaxb_lib/activation.jar:$APP_HOME/bin/jaxb_lib/jaxb-impl.jar:$APP_HOME/bin/jaxb_lib/jaxb-xjc.jar:$APP_HOME/bin/jaxb_lib/jaxb-core.jar:$APP_HOME/bin/jaxb_lib/jaxb-jxc.jar:$APP_HOME/bin/jaxb_lib/jaxb-api.jar:<etc etc...DO NOT REMOVE THE OTHER JARS!...>
```

Comment: Did you download those files?