# Android SDK Manager throws Exception [Java 11 issue. Please Read Description]

Tags: flutter, java-11

I'm trying to set up flutter on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine.

When I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` It prompts me to update the SDK like so -

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run:
/home/<username>/Android/SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

When I run it, I encounter an Exception - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345147/android-sdk-manager-throw-exception-with-java-9) suggests changing `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` in `sdkmanager` to

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" --add-modules java.xml.bind'
```

This seems to work in Java 9/10. However, I use Java 11 and unfortunately the `java.xml.bind` module and `java.se.ee` module has been discontinued from Java 11 -

```
java version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Is there a way to fix this in Java 11? Or do I have to downgrade to Java 9/10?

Answer (score 0):

flutter supports java 1.8
so, try install java 1.8

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?